# Change constraint of clob column

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, clob

I want to change a `NOT NULL` constraint of a clob column to a `NULL` constraint. However, when trying

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN myClobCol clob NULL;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE myTable modify myClobCol clob NULL;
```

I get the following errors:

```
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

or

```
ORA-22859: invalid modification of columns
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to use a temp column in this case too? I know the scenario of changing the data type from clob to varchar2 by using a temp column but here I just want to change the constraint. Why this is not possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ORA-22859` error is raised by Oracle on any attempt to modify a `CLOB`, `NCLOB`, or `BLOB` column data type. This comes from a column limitation for the so called `LOB` data types.

When specifying the new type in the `ALTER TABLE` command, as in your case:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column CLOB NULL;
```

The validation is triggered and the query is aborted as Oracle considers changing from `CLOB` to `CLOB` to be equally invalid.

The good thing is the `ALTER TABLE` command supports omitting pieces of the column definition you want to left intact. So, by changing it to:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column NULL;
```

You'll be able to drop the nullity constraint while keeping the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare
  col_nullable varchar2(1);
begin
  select nullable into col_nullable
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name = 'myTable'
  and   column_name = 'myClobCol';

  if col_nullable = 'N' then
    execute immediate 'alter table mytable modify (myClobCol null)';
  end if;
end;
```